# 68k Assembly Subtraction small value from big value

Tags: assembly, easy68k

My script take input of two numbers subtract the second number from the first and output the result:

```
CR          EQU     $0D
LF          EQU     $0A

START   ORG $1000   

*---------- Code for output ---------*

            LEA     MSG1,a1
            MOVE.B  #14,d0
            TRAP    #15


*---------- Code for input ---------*

    MOVE.B  #4,d0
            TRAP    #15

            move.b  d1,d2

*---------- Code for output ---------*

            LEA     MSG2,a1
            MOVE.B  #14,d0
            TRAP    #15


*---------- Code for input ---------*

    MOVE.B  #4,d0
            TRAP    #15

            sub.b   d2,d1

            move    #3,d0   
    trap    #15

*---------- Halt Simulator ---------*   

    MOVE.B  #9,d0
    TRAP    #15

* Stop execution
    STOP    #$2000

MSG1         DC.B    'Enter a first number: ',0
MSG2         DC.B    'Enter a second number: ',0

    END START   end of program with start address specified
```

If first number = 50

And second number = 100

Result is = 50

but if first number = 100

and second number = 50

Result is 206

Why is it 206? what is happening? and what is the significance of 256 in this operation.

**Also very good resource that explains this is on the following link:**

http://mrjester.hapisan.com/04_MC68/Sect04Part02/Index.html

Comment: one of the beauties of twos complement is that signed and unsigned addition and subtraction are all the same thing.  whether or not the inputs are considered signed or unsigned is strictly in the eyes of the beholder the logic doesnt know nor care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's perform the subtraction in hexadecimal on 1 byte:
32H - 64H = 00H - 32H = CEH (two's complement) with carry bit set to 1
CEH in hexadecimal = 206 in decimal
So your observed result is the expected one.